# Верстка под ie7

Tags: html, css

Как можно поставить один элемент поверх второго,z-index не помогает ,при том что у нижнего position:relative,а у верхнего position:absolute;

Comment: Вариантов несколько. Можно увидеть верстку?

Comment: Верстку ммм нет ) Объясню словами: сделан кастомный SELECT(то есть как тэг HTML только из DIV-ов который выпадает вниз по клику),а когда он выпадает вниз то INPUT в DIV-е перекрывает его,во всех браузрех кроме ie7 не работает,в ie8 все нормально.

Comment: Простите, но ie7 must die! Уже давно есть 8 и 9. Под 8 имеет смысл верстать т.к. 9я в xp не ставится. Лучше ставьте заглушку на ie7 со ссылкой на скачивание 8го.

Comment: Это не моя прихоть ,это начальник сказал верстка => 7 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело не в самих элементах, а в их родителях, нужно найди ближайшего родителя элемента с position:relative и поставить ему z-index, больший, чем у ребенка.

Comment: Ок сейчас попробую и скажу результат

Comment: чет не получается или я делаю не правильно...

Comment: должно получаться, может нужно найти еще одного следующего родителя с position: relative, поэкспериментируйте со значением z-index для них, если не получается, тогда нужно посмотреть на верстку и стили к ним, чтобы помочь

Comment: Друг огромное спасибо посидел поковырял и сделал таки!Спасибо )
В родителях разобрался ,получилось )

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить

```
//zoom: 100%
```

ко этим элементам, у меня решались некоторые проблемы верстки, связанные с position

Comment: Уже сделал ) Спасибо !